# Inserting custom field to core field group

Tags: custom-fields

https://civicrm.org/blogs/lobo/extending-contact-demographic-information-custom-group shows some hints how I can add custom fields to the core demographics, but that was for civicrm 3.1. I gave it a try anyhow, but got stuck with

```
$whatever &= CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::getTree('Contact', $form, $form->getVar('id'), CIVICRM_CANVASS_DEMOGRAPHICS_ID, null, null );
```

Do the hints still apply to 4.6+ ? How would you do it today?

$form->getVar('id') returns nothing. What id are we talking about here? Could it be that it returns only something in edit forms? and I don't quite understand what the constant CIVICRM_CANVASS_DEMOGRAPHICS_ID is.